# JSDOM - ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80 when running test in Azure DevOps

Tags: vue.js, azure-devops, jestjs

When the job is running on Azure DevOps `yarn test:unit` the following error happens multiple times. This does not prevent tests to pass. The project runs `vue` and `jest` for testing. When runs locally, no errors occur.

### jest.config.js

```
const Vue = require('vue');
const Vuetify = require('vuetify');

Vue.use(Vuetify);

module.exports = {
  preset: '@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest/presets/typescript-and-babel',
  collectCoverage: false,
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    'src/**/*.{js,vue}',
    '!src/registerServiceWorker.js',
    '!src/helpers.js',
    '!src/constants/**',
    '!src/mixins/**',
    '!src/plugins/**',
    '!src/router/**',
    '!src/test/**',
    '!src/main.js', // No need to cover bootstrap file
  ],
  transform: {
    'vee-validate/dist/rules': 'babel-jest',
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '<roodDir>/node_modules/(?!vee-validate/dist/rules)',
  ],

  testEnvironmentOptions: {
    // Allow test environment to fire onload event
    // See https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1816#issuecomment-355188615
    resources: 'usable',
  },
};
```

### axios.js

```
let baseURL = '';
switch (process.env.NODE_ENV) {
  case 'development': {
    baseURL = 'https://localhost:44359/api/v1';
    break;
  }
  case 'production': {
    baseURL = 'webapi/api/v1';
    break;
  }
  case 'docker': {
    const port = process.env.VUE_APP_WebAPI_PORT;
    const path = process.env.VUE_APP_WebAPI_Path;
    const version = process.env.VUE_APP_WebAPI_Version;
    const url = new URL(window.location.origin);
    url.port = port;
    baseURL = `${url.origin.toString()}/${path}/${version}`;
    break;
  }
  default: baseURL = 'webapi/api/v1';
}

/* eslint-disable import/prefer-default-export */
export const http = axios.create({
  baseURL,
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  paramsSerializer: (params) => {
    Object.keys(params).forEach((key) => {
      if (_isArray(params[key]) && !params[key].length) {
        delete params[key];
      }
    });
    return qs.stringify(params, { arrayFormat: 'repeat' });
  },
});
```

### Error

> Error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
> at Object.dispatchError (/home/vsts/work/1/s/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr-utils.js:54:19)
> at Request. (/home/vsts/work/1/s/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xmlhttprequest.js:675:20)
> at Request.emit (events.js:327:22)
> at Request.onRequestError (/home/vsts/work/1/s/node_modules/request/request.js:877:8)
> at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:315:20)
> at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:426:9)
> at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
> at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
> at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) undefined
> console.error node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/virtual-console.js:29

Any help would be welcome

[image]

Comment: Can you show your pipeline? How do you build and test this project?

Comment: I attached the job that is run. The project is build with `yarn:build` command which essentially runs `vue-cli-service build` and testing is carried out with `vue-cli-service test:unit`

Answer (score 0):

This error could be due to i18n usage. I have noticed that when I have the same problem and debug it, it gets this error because it cannot access localization files. You can use the moduleNameMapper setting as a solution.

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#modulenamemapper-objectstring-string--arraystring